# How do I join two rdds based on a common field?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

I am very new to **Scala** and learning to work with `RDDs`. I have two csv files which have the following headers and data:
**csv1.txt**

```
id,"location", "zipcode" 
1, "a", "12345"
2, "b", "67890"
3, "c" "54321"
```

**csv2.txt**

```
"location_x", "location_y", trip_hrs
"a", "b", 1
"a", "c", 3
"b", "c", 2
"a", "b", 1
"c", "b", 2
```

Basically, **csv1** data is a distinct set of locations and zip codes, whereas **csv2** data has the trip duration between location_x and location_y.

The common piece of information in these two data sets is *location* in **csv1** and *location_x* in **csv2** even though they have different header names.

I would like to create two `RDDs` with one containing the data from **csv1** and the other from **csv2**.

Then I would like to `join` these two `RDDs` and return the location, zipcode, and sum of all trip times from that location as shown below:

```
("a", "zipcode", 5)
("b", "zipcode", 2)
("c", "zipcode", 2)
```

I was wondering if one of you can assist me with this problem. Thanks.

Comment: ok, and now what is the problem? Reading from CSV and then do the join, everything is in the Spark docs. It is so trivial that there is no need to ask here. Read both CSV into a dataframe, then do the join. approx. 5 lines of code.

Comment: I was able to pull in the data from each CSV file into two separate RDDs; locationRDD and tripRDD. When I do a foreach(println) on each, I see all of the data was extracted correctly from each CSV. Now I am wondering if the joins of the two rdds can be done without using dataframe. I also need to sum up the total trip time for each location and have the result be displayed as ("location", "zipcode", sum_of_trip_times). It may be 5 lines of code which takes 2 minutes, but may be not for people who just picked up a whole new programming language with syntax totally different from C++/ C#

Comment: "Zip array" might help https://alvinalexander.com/scala/how-to-merge-sequential-collection-pairs-zip-unzip-scala-cookbook/

Comment: @LearningBigData well, the main issue is not showing any code so people think you didn't try anything. Then my first question is, why RDD and not DataFrame? Anyways, if you want join on RDDs you have to make `PairRDD` out of your RDD first, i.e. you have to create key-value structure because join always happens on the key. For example if you have an RDD of tuples you could do `rdd.map(tuple => (tuple._1, tuple)))` - I hope you get the idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will give you the code (a complete app in **IntelliJ**) with some explanations. I hope it can be helpful.

Please read the `Spark` documentation for the explicit details.

[working-with-key-value-pairs](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/rdd-programming-guide.html#working-with-key-value-pairs)

This problem can be done with **Spark Dataframes**, you can try for yourself.

```scala
import org.apache.log4j.{Level, Logger}
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession

object Joining {

  val spark = SparkSession
    .builder()
    .appName("Joining")
    .master("local[*]")
    .config("spark.sql.shuffle.partitions", "4") //Change to a more reasonable default number of partitions for our data
    .config("spark.app.id", "Joining")  // To silence Metrics warning
    .getOrCreate()

  val sc = spark.sparkContext

  val path = "/home/cloudera/files/tests/"

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    Logger.getRootLogger.setLevel(Level.ERROR)

    try {

      // read the files
      val file1 = sc.textFile(s"${path}join1.csv")
      val header1 = file1.first // extract the header of the file
      val file2 = sc.textFile(s"${path}join2.csv")
      val header2 = file2.first // extract the header of the file

      val rdd1 = file1
        .filter(line => line != header1) // to leave out the header
        .map(line => line.split(",")) // split the lines => Array[String]
        .map(arr => (arr(1).trim,arr(2).trim)) // to make up a pairRDD with arr(1) as key and zipcode

      val rdd2 = file2
          .filter(line => line != header2)
          .map(line => line.split(",")) // split the lines => Array[String]
          .map(arr => (arr(0).trim, arr(2).trim.toInt)) // to make up a pairRDD with arr(0) as key and trip_hrs

      val joined = rdd1 // join the pairRDD by its keys
          .join(rdd2)
          .cache()  // cache joined in memory

      joined.foreach(println) // checking data
      println("**************")

//      ("c",("54321",2))
//      ("b",("67890",2))
//      ("a",("12345",1))
//      ("a",("12345",3))
//      ("a",("12345",1))

      val result = joined.reduceByKey({ case((zip, time), (zip1, time1) ) => (zip, time + time1) })

      result.map({case( (id,(zip,time)) ) => (id, zip, time)}).foreach(println) // checking output

//      ("b","67890",2)
//      ("c","54321",2)
//      ("a","12345",5)

      // To have the opportunity to view the web console of Spark: http://localhost:4041/
      println("Type whatever to the console to exit......")
      scala.io.StdIn.readLine()
    } finally {
      sc.stop()
      println("SparkContext stopped")
      spark.stop()
      println("SparkSession stopped")
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to show me how pairRdd and join works. Appreciate your comments in the code.

Answer (score 0):

If you can read CSV into RDD already, Trips can be summarized, and then joined with Locations:

```
val tripsSummarized = trips
  .map({ case (location, _, hours) => (location, hours) })
  .reduceByKey((hoursTotal, hoursIncrement) => hoursTotal + hoursIncrement)

val result = locations
  .map({ case (_, location, zipCode) => (location, zipCode) })
  .join(tripsSummarized)
  .map({case (location, (zipCode, hoursTotal)) => (location, zipCode, hoursTotal) })
```

If locations without trips are required, "leftOuterJoin" can be used.